# Plot time series and forecast simultaneously using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a time series with forecast and confidence interval data, I wanted to plot them simultaneously using ggplot2. I'm doing it by the code below:

```
set.seed(321)
library(ggplot2)
#create some dummy  data similar to mine

sample<-rnorm(350)
forecast<-rnorm(24)
upper<-forecast+2*sd(forecast)
lower<-forecast-2*sd(forecast)


## wrap data into a data.frame
df1 = data.frame(time = seq(325,350,length=26), M = sample[325:350], isin = "observations")
df2 = data.frame(time = seq(351,374,length=24), M = forecast , isin = "my_forecast")
df3 = data.frame(time = seq(351,374,length=24), M = upper ,isin = "upper_bound")
df4 = data.frame(time = seq(351,374,length=24), M = lower, isin = "lower_bound")
df = rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4)

## ggplot object 
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = M, color = isin)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

How can I join upper and lower lines in one color? and also how can I set specific colors to forecast and sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `scale_colour_manual`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = M, color = isin)) + geom_line() + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=c(observations='blue', my_forecast='red', upper_bound='black', lower_bound='black'))
```

[image]

**edit**

This is another option, inspired by @rnso answer.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = time, y = M)) + geom_line(colour='blue') +
    geom_smooth(aes(x=time, y=M, ymax=upper_bound, ymin=lower_bound), 
                colour='red', data=df5, stat='identity')
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the last option. Take in account that df5 should be df2, upper_bound should be upper and lower_bound should be lower for  my simulated data. Just because somebody else could be interested in. Thanks Matthew.

Comment: About the option inspire by @rnso, I wanted to add a legend with observations and my_forecoast. I use ggplot(df1, aes(x = time, y = M)) + geom_line(colour='blue') +
    geom_smooth(aes(x=time, y=M, ymax=upper_bound, ymin=lower_bound), 
                colour='red', data=df5, stat='identity') +scale_colour_manual(values=c(observations='blue', my_forecast='red')).  It dislayed the same plot without a legend, any help...

Comment: best to post a new question.

Answer (score 6):

Following may be useful:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=df1, aes(x = time, y = M, color = isin)) + 
  stat_smooth(data=df2, aes(x = time, y = M, color = isin))
```

[image]

`'method'` option can also be used in `stat_smooth()`