# r: How to connect line breaks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Reusing the example in this question, but for a different question;
[Plot time series and forecast simultaneously using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042774/plot-time-series-and-forecast-simultaneously-using-ggplot2)

As you can see, there is a gap between 'my observation' and 'my forecast' (between 350, and 351).

Why is there a gap? I have a 1 day forecast, and the forecast line itself is completely missing from the chart. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your last 'observation' was made when time=350.

```
df[df$time > 349 & df$time <= 351, ]
##   time          M         isin
## 26  350 -0.2180864 observations
## 27  351  1.2246175  my_forecast
## 51  351  3.7502526  upper_bound
## 75  351 -1.3010176  lower_bound
```

You can add a data point at time=351 and isin=observations, if you want to connect them.

```
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(
  time = c(351), M = c(1.2246175), isin = c("observations")
))
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = M, color = isin)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks, back to my scenario, due to the 1 day forecast, i assume geom_line doesn't draw a line because there is only 1 point, is it better that i plot geom_point for the 1 day forecast (only 1 row of my_forecast at 351), and maintain geom_line for the observation? I understand your method applied to 'forecast' works too, but am interested to maintain 1 observation for 'forecast' 'isin' for other purposes.